# how to setup to see previous commit messages in RStudio

Tags: git, rstudio

I want to see the previous commit messages in RStudio, so I click to "history" tab in Git .

As the following images, there doesn't seem to show commit messages in the panel.

Could you tell me how to setup to see the previous commit messages?[image]

Answer (score -1):

The *subject* column you have here **is** the commit message, or more precisely its subject.

That is, commit messages are in two parts, subject (which is often a summary) and body.

For the one selected in your screen capture, the subject is just "[update]", which, granted, is not very informative.

When you're outputing commit messages from the command line, you can use placeholders in specified [formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) and obtain either subject (`%s`) or body (`%b`), or of course both (`%B`). However, I couldn't say if RStudio allows for this to be configured by the user in the display you showed.